# On the basis of a free module over a PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

We have a famous theorem for a vector space which states that "every set of generators of a vector space $V$ over a field $F$ contains a basis of $V$". Is this statement true for a free module (probably over a PID) instead of the vector space $V$?

Comment: Is this statement true...?

Comment: What do you think, and why?

Answer (score 5):

No.  Consider the set $\{2,3\}$, which generates $\mathbb{Z}$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module; it does not contain a basis of $\mathbb{Z}$.